# Display int value as label

Tags: ios, objective-c

Good evening, I am new to iOS and have a real quick question.

All I need help with is how I can get my label "Label" to reflect the value of "Number" which is a primitive int I have set as 25. The problem is, instead of showing 25, it shows 27896. Im sure this is 25 in another format of data, but can anyone help me with what code to use to display the actual int value of 25?

I would like this to happen when the user presses the button with the id "Execute"

Here is my code. Thanks!

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

int Number = @"25";


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)Execute:(id)sender {

    Number = Number * 2;

    [_Label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", Number]];



}
@end
```

Thanks guys, your help would be very much apreciated.

Comment: @"25" is a NSNumber constant, not an int. iVars should not begin with capital letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

int number = 25;


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)Execute:(id)sender {

    number = number * 2;

    [_Label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", number]];



}
@end
```

or

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

NSNumber number = @25;


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)Execute:(id)sender {

    number = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[number intValue ] * 2];
// or
    number = @([number intValue ] * 2);

    [_Label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", number]];



}
@end
```

What you did is, you created an `int` named `Number` (which should be `number` anyway) and assigned it a constant `NSString` object with the value `"25"` (as string). 
`@25` creates an `NSNumber` object with the value of `25`.

Answer (score 2):

First you write

```
int Number = @"25";
```

In your code change with

```
int Number = 25;
```

And if you want to display int as string then your code is right ;

```
[_Label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", Number]];
```

Comment: Ok, I have changed it from @"25"; to just 25; But what is the best code to use when displaying it as an int with the value of 25 instead of a string? As it is it is giving me 17096. Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: @SandyBites there is no UI element available that displays int as int. Using a UILabel or so displaying the string representation of an int (or NSNumber) is the closest that you can get.

Answer (score 0):

Read this [guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Introduction/Introduction.html) and use properties. Good luck.